# Adding psycopg2 to setup for dev

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, psycopg2, packaging

How can I run pip install my python package so that it can use psycopg2?

Currently **psycopg2-binary** is not allowed due to clash with libraries liable to produce segfault issues.

This is for both deployment, on Ubuntu, and development on Mac or Windows.
So I need for the deployment for production script to work with no issue, and when a developer runs:

```
pip install -e '.[dev]'
```

This should set up the environment for local development.

Is it possible to have some logic to intercept for setting up in a local development environment and install libpq-dev and python3-dev for Developer machines?

Or are there any tips for developing within Docker?

```
    install_requires=[  # library for production
        ...,
        'psycopg2==2.8.*',
        ...
    ],
    extras_require={
        'dev': [
         ...
        ],  # custom library for development
```

The undelying Docker images have the requisite libpq-dev and python3-dev required.

Comment: So what's the problem here? If the dev libraries for building psycopg2 are available on the developer machines, things should be dandy.

Comment: Rather the additional step of installing the dependencies on the dev machine.
libpq-dev can't be added as an additional dependency since it is a binary and can't be pip installed, and also the *install_requires* runs before the *extra_requires*.


Some way for a shells script to run before the *install_requires*, there's still the Windows/Mac(homebrew) issue to resolve

Comment: The Windows/Mac issue can be resolved with a custom PyPI index where you've pre-built wheels for your developers' platforms (and `pip --find-links`). Another possible solution is a README file...